# Segfault while trying to fill the yuv image for rtsp streaming

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am capturing the video stream from a window, and I want to restream it to my rtsp proxy server. However, it seems I can't write the frame properly, but I can show the said frame in a SDL window. Here is my code :

```
int StreamHandler::storeStreamData()
{
// Allocate video frame
pFrame = av_frame_alloc();

// Allocate an AVFrame structure
pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();
if (pFrameRGB == NULL)
    throw myExceptions("Error : Can't alloc the frame.");

// Determine required buffer size and allocate buffer
numBytes = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, pCodecCtx->width,
    pCodecCtx->height);
buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes * sizeof(uint8_t));

// Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameRGB
avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
    pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

//InitSdlDrawBack();

// initialize SWS context for software scaling

sws_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width,
    pCodecCtx->height,
    pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
    pCodecCtx->width,
    pCodecCtx->height,
    pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
    SWS_LANCZOS,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);

SetPixelArray();
FfmpegEncoder enc("rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream");

i = 0;
while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {
    if (packet.stream_index == videoindex) {
        // Decode video frame
        avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
        if (frameFinished) {
            i++;
            //DrawFrame();

            sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
                pFrame->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height,
                pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize);
            enc.encodeFrame(pFrameRGB, i);
        }
    }
    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}
// Free the RGB image
av_free(buffer);
av_frame_free(&pFrameRGB);

// Free the YUV frame
av_frame_free(&pFrame);

// Close the codecs
avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);
avcodec_close(pCodecCtxOrig);

// Close the video file
avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

return 0;
}

void StreamHandler::SetPixelArray()
{
yPlaneSz = pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height;
uvPlaneSz = pCodecCtx->width * pCodecCtx->height / 4;
yPlane = (Uint8*)malloc(yPlaneSz);
uPlane = (Uint8*)malloc(uvPlaneSz);
vPlane = (Uint8*)malloc(uvPlaneSz);
if (!yPlane || !uPlane || !vPlane)
    throw myExceptions("Error : Can't create pixel array.");

uvPitch = pCodecCtx->width / 2;
}
```

Here I fill the YUV image and write the packet.

```
void FfmpegEncoder::encodeFrame(AVFrame * frame, int frameCount)
{
AVPacket    pkt = { 0 };
int         got_pkt;

av_init_packet(&pkt);
frame->pts = frameCount;

FillYuvImage(frame, frameCount, this->pCodecCtx->width, this->pCodecCtx->height);

if (avcodec_encode_video2(this->pCodecCtx, &pkt, frame, &got_pkt) < 0)
    throw myExceptions("Error: failed to encode the frame. FfmpegEncoder.cpp l:61\n");

//if the frame is well encoded
if (got_pkt) {
    pkt.stream_index = this->st->index;
    pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, this->pCodecCtx->time_base, this->st->time_base, AVRounding(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
    if (av_write_frame(this->outFormatCtx, &pkt) < 0)
        throw myExceptions("Error: failed to write video frame. FfmpegEncoder.cpp l:68\n");
}
}

void FfmpegEncoder::FillYuvImage(AVFrame * pict, int frame_index, int width, int height)
{
int x, y, i;

i = frame_index;

for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < width / 2; x++)
        pict->data[0][y * pict->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
}
for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < width / 2; x++)
    {
        pict->data[1][y * pict->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
        pict->data[2][y * pict->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + y + i * 5; //segault here
    }
}
}
```

The "FillYuvImage" method is copied from a FFMPEG example, but It does not work for me. If I don't call it, the "av_write_frame" function won't work (segfault too).

EDIT : Here is my output context and codec initialization.

```
FfmpegEncoder::FfmpegEncoder(char *url)
{
AVRational      tmp_time_base;
AVDictionary*   options = NULL;

this->pCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
if (this->pCodec == NULL)
    throw myExceptions("Error: Can't initialize the encoder. FfmpegEncoder.cpp l:9\n");

this->pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(this->pCodec);

//Alloc output context
if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outFormatCtx, NULL, "rtsp", url) < 0)
    throw myExceptions("Error: Can't alloc stream output. FfmpegEncoder.cpp l:17\n");

this->st = avformat_new_stream(this->outFormatCtx, this->pCodec);

if (this->st == NULL)
    throw myExceptions("Error: Can't create stream . FfmpegEncoder.cpp l:22\n");

av_dict_set(&options, "vprofile", "main", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);

tmp_time_base.num = 1;
tmp_time_base.den = 60;

//TODO : parse these values
this->pCodecCtx->bit_rate = 3000000;
this->pCodecCtx->width = 1280;
this->pCodecCtx->height = 720;
//This set the fps. 60fps at this point.
this->pCodecCtx->time_base = tmp_time_base;
//Add a intra frame every 12 frames
this->pCodecCtx->gop_size = 12;
this->pCodecCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

//Open Codec, using the context + x264 options
if (avcodec_open2(this->pCodecCtx, this->pCodec, &options) < 0)
    throw myExceptions("Error: Can't open the codec. FfmpegEncoder.cpp l:43\n");

if (avcodec_copy_context(this->st->codec, this->pCodecCtx) != 0) {
    throw myExceptions("Error : Can't copy codec context. FfmpegEncoder.cpp : l.46");
}

av_dump_format(this->outFormatCtx, 0, url, 1);

if (avformat_write_header(this->outFormatCtx, NULL) != 0)
    throw myExceptions("Error: failed to connect to RTSP server. FfmpegEncoder.cpp l:48\n");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger like `gdb`? It can tell you what line is cuasing the segfault

Comment: I have already found the line that segfault (there is a comment in the code, //segfault here)
But I don't know why it segfaults.

Comment: My guess would be that `y * pict->linesize[2] + x` is out of bounds... Check the values in the line before with a debugger or let them print to the console to see what happens.

Comment: @SimonKraemer Yeah but the problem is that the code is from the ffmpeg example sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < width / 2; x++)
    {
         pict->data[1][y * pict->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
         pict->data[2][y * pict->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + y + i * 5; //segault here
    }
}
```

should be

```
for (y = 0; y < height / 2; y++) // Divide height by 2, you need only every other line
{
    for (x = 0; x < width / 2; x++)
    {
         pict->data[1][y * pict->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
         pict->data[2][y * pict->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + y + i * 5; //segault here
    }
}
```

YUV 420 means you have one U and V sample for each 2x2 square, but with your code you are doing a sample for each 1x2 square, obviously going out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, the segfault is fixed, but now, the av_write_frame is segfaulting ...

Comment: @tankyx your code does not show how you create the `outFormatCtx` variable - without that I can't give you any more advice.

Comment: indeed, I have added it to the post.

Comment: @tankyx - ok, now I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. What is this rtsp proxy server? How does it accept the incoming streams? Why do you think that the ffmpeg rtsp client is able to work with your proxy server?

Comment: I want to capture the video of a window, and push the stream to a Wowza rtsp server. I have already tried with the ffmpeg cli and it worked perfectly.

    `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -i title="[TITLE]" -r 60 -vcodec libx264 -vb 3000000 -g 60 -vprofile main -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ab 128000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -strict experimental -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/myStream`

here is the command I used and I want to reproduce in C++

Comment: @tankyx - ok, well it's hard to tell, can you check with Wireshark or netstat if the outgoing RTSP connection is even opened to get a better understanding what exactly is happening?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't respond before. I can connect to the rtsp server (by calling avformat_write_header), but then the call to av_write_frame just keeps on feeling.

Comment: @tankyx, since you accepted the answer did you manage to fix the second crash?

Comment: Nop, I have opened a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724543/ffmpeg-can-write-the-header-to-the-rtsp-server-but-not-the-frame) as you fixed the bug that was the subject of the question.